# framer motion list animation

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I'm building a todo-list app just for practice. I need to implement an animation where it will smoothly slide down when completed and slide up when undone. I'm obviously working in react would like some help on how to implement it in framer motion. I'm quite new to animations, so any help is appreciated. I'm also confused how to keep the animations in sync with the state changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `layoutId` prop on the motion component. If both elements have the same `layoutId` motion will animate the change for you. Also, having a codesandbox or something would be nice to check the code.

You can check out docs here: https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/#shared-layout-animations and here https://www.framer.com/docs/layout-group/